# Difference between two exception handling

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I'm new to python and learning a bit about exception handling for a bit of code that I'm writing. Came across two ways of handling an exception that avoid the problem of catching a keyboard interrupt and wanted to know if there was a significant difference between these two following methods.

```
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    raise
except:
    some code...
```

and

```
except Exception as e: 
    some code...
```

I have learned that they both avoid catching Keyboard Interrupt but am just curious if they are just syntactically different and do the same thing or if there is an advantage to using one over the other in certain scenarios, thanks.

Comment: Hi, I thing that they are same in essence - both catches only the exceptions which are subclasses of `Exception`. Only in the first, you are catching also the `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit` which you raise right away - so it is unnecessary (If you don't do any processing on them). In the second you save the Exception instance as `e` which can be useful for some logging etc.. But you can do it in the first case also.

Answer (score 0):

Well in your first example you are only catching the two exceptions, and in your second example you are catching ALL exceptions that the program might give.

So if you try to get a value from a dictionary with a key that isnt in the dictionary you would get `KeyError`, it wouldnt be catched by the first example, and the program would crash.

In the second example it would be catched though.

What is best? Well always try to handle the exceptions that are related to what you are gonna do, so be specific like in the first case.

Comment: Hi, I don't thing that you are correct, because, he is catching all cases of `Exception` subclases in both cases. In the first using the bare except, in the second using the `except Exception as e`. The `KeyboardInterupt` is not subclass of `Exception` thus is not catched.

Comment: @MarekSchwarz You are correct, I just answered to fast before adding my answer. Thansk for correcting me